# Ambiguous reference to ViewModel in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC project .NET 4.5, using VS 2013

When I start debugging the project, I get the following error on my Viewmodel:

```
Ambiguous reference:
  Vin.Model.ViewModel.Bottle.BottleDetailsViewmodel
  Vin.Model.ViewModel.Bottle.BottleDetailsViewmodel
match
```

If I stop debugging and clean the solution everything is OK, but as soon as I start debugging the error is back.

Perhaps I also should point out that this is only occurs in the views, not in the controller class or anywhere else in the solution.

Comment: This often happens if there are 2 versions of the `DLL` containing the `ViewModels` in your bin folder (e.g. if you've just renamed your project). Purge your bin folder and rebuild.

Comment: Ah... I have some problems with reference to EF6 on the build server so I fiddled around with the Configuration Manager (without success though). I'll have to look into this. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction StuartLC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

- Cleaning the solution and rebuilding
- Ensure the version of the .Net framework your projects are pointing at are the same
- Clear your Bin & Obj folders

Comment: Yes, but I have to do that every time. I also want to be able to have intellisense while debugging.

Comment: It still is the same :(. After a build the project I end up with one dll under each project that references the Model project. Under the Model project itself there are two, one under obj and one under bin. This is how it should be or isn't it?

Comment: Did you delete the bin and obj folders for all of your projects?

Comment: Yes Jamez. I'll try to restart VS and purge files before I open the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following,

it is not the complex one .
just add fully qualified name that is ,
model."class name"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).